# AVRoutePickerView doesn't pick up change to route made by overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, avkit

I start a VoIP call using CallKit, use `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)` to force the audio to speaker, and then open an `AVRoutePickerView`.

The selected output in the view is `iPhone`-- the ear speaker on the iPhone. I would expect it to show instead that `speaker` is selected.

What could be causing this? Should I be forcing the output to the speaker in a different way? Is there a different way I can expose the route choosing functionality?

What's strange is that if you lock the phone and look at the CallKit UI, it shows that it is routing to speaker

Comment: I have same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: just faced the same problem, did u find the solution? @NikedLab

Comment: just faced the same problem, did u find the solution? @kumail

Answer (score -2):

I encountered the same problem. In my code, I overrode the audio route to .none and it worked indeed. But the AvRoutePickerView showed .speaker selected. It confuse me.